# Sublime Text 3 Python build not working

Tags: python, windows, sublimetext3

I have been trying to get into Python today and I want to use Sublime text 3 as an editor but when I try to do anything I just get this error:

```
C:\python33\python.exe: can't find '__main__' module in ''
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['C:\\python33\\python.exe', '-u', '']]
[dir: C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3]
[path:  C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32
\WindowsPowerShell\    v1.0\;C:\Anaconda;C:\Anaconda\Scripts]
```

My build for Python is:

```
{
"cmd": ["C:\\python33\\python.exe", "-u", "$file"],
"file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
"selector": "source.python",
"encoding": "utf8",
"path": "C:\\Python33\\"
}
```

Could anyone help me find the error?

Answer (score 0):

This is not an error with ST3, rather your Python script. Try changing your main class in your script to this:

```
name = __main__:
```